# Rewrite and redirect with modrewrite

Tags: .htaccess

I am simply trying to rewrite and redirect automatically this:

From `mysite.com/sub/index.php?channel=rai1`

To `mysite.com/sub/channel-rai1.html`

I've tried with this:

```
RewriteRule ^sub/channel-([^/]*)\.html$ /sub/index.php?channel=$1 [L]
```

but the problem is that the redirection does not happen. Why?

Comment: Redirection not going to happen because you have not specify any redirection flag. But this will internally map to pattern url.

Comment: i tried with this code: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/sub/index\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^channel=([^/]*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://vvv.mysite.com/sub/channel-%1.html? [R=301]  but i get 404 not found

Comment: You have `vvv` instead of `www` in your URL

Comment: I wrote in that way to shorten... i get 404 error anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing your rewrite rule to:

```
RewriteRule ^sub/channel-([^/]*)\.html$ /sub/index.php?channel=$1 [R=301]
```

will work. You were writing the rule, but you weren't telling it to change it in the browser.

`[L]` tell it to stop applying any rules that follow. `[R=301]` will do the actual redirection of the url to the new one and tell browers/search engines that the new url is the permanent one to use. You can use `[R=301, L]` which will combine the two.

EDIT:
I read the question wrong, my apologies

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /sub/index\.php\?channel=(.*)&data=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^sub/index.php /sub/channel-%2-%3.html? [R,L]


#Internal rewrite
RewriteRule ^sub/channel-([^/]*)-(.*)\.html$ /sub/index.php?channel=$1&data=$2 [L]
```

The above should change `http://example.com/sub/index.php?channel=NBC&data=2012/02/12` to `http://example.com/sub/channel-NBC-2012/02/12.html`

Comment: i tried, but the redirection of the url occurs from newurl to oldurl. So i get again index.php?channel=$1

Comment: @user2490424 So you need opposite? old to new?

Comment: Sorry, but i've another problem. The url can have another value "get", so the url becomes sub/channel-NBC&data=31/03/2014.html and i get 404 error. Can you help me? What i have to do to rewrite url from sub/channel-NBC&data=31/03/2014.html to sub/channel-NBC-tomorrow.html

Comment: I can add the data to it, will the data always be the next day?

Comment: Yes, the data will always be the next day.

Comment: Yes it is possible, but you will need to get the next days date on the actual page itself because changing the date to `tomorrow` can't be undone.

Comment: What do you mean by `it's the same`?

Comment: You can change the url in sub/channel-NBC-"value of data".html ?

Comment: Ok, now there is another problem, when you go to the page sub/channel-NBC-31/03/2014.html you don't read the css. I saw the link to the source page and the css link is sub/channel-NBC-31/03/css/style.css instead of sub/css/style.css

Comment: in the css link try add `/` at the start of the link or add <base href="websitelink"> in the head tag of each page.

Comment: Nothing happens. However all the links of the page are corrupt in that way.

Comment: Hi Howlin, i tried to add `RewriteBase /demop1/` but the redirect doesn't work. Why?